# Removing values from a vector that are not duplicated at least x number of times

Tags: r, unique, duplicates

Given a vector:

eg.:

```
a = c(1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 3, 5, 3, 2, 1, 5, 3)
```

Using `a[a%in%a[duplicated(a)]]` I can remove values not duplicated. However, it only works for values that are only present once.

How would I go on about removing all values that aren't present in this thrice? (or more, in other situations)

The expected result would be:

```
2 2 5 3 5 3 2 5 3
```

with 1 and 4 removed, as they are only present twice and once

Answer (score 8):

You can do this in one line with the `ave` function:

```
a[ave(a, a, FUN=length) >= 3]
# [1] 2 2 5 3 5 3 2 5 3
```

The call to `ave(a, a, FUN=length)` returns, for each element `a[i]` in vector `a`, the total number of times `a[i]` appears within `a`. Then you can subset `a`, limiting to the indices where the total number of times is 3 or more.

Answer (score 5):

Reasonably straightforward (longer than using `ave` but possibly more comprehensible):

```
x <- c(1,2,2,4,5,3,5,3,2,1,5,3)
tt <- table(x)   ## tabulate
## find relevant values
ttr <- as.numeric(names(tt)[tt>=3])
x[x %in% ttr]  ## subset
```

Comment: `a[a %in% sort(unique(a))[table(a)>=3]]` as a variation on a theme.